# Compare function argument of typedef struct with its instance declaration in C

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I'm trying to write the following function,

```
#define CW  0
#define CCW 1

typedef struct
{
  uint8_t dir;
  uint8_t sr;
  uint8_t pwml;
  uint8_t en;
  uint8_t state;
  uint8_t runstate;
  uint8_t endstop_status;
} Motor_Params;

Motor_Params Motor_M1;
Motor_Params Motor_M2;
Motor_Params Motor_M3;
Motor_Params Motor_M4;

void Home_Motor(Motor_Params *motor, uint8_t dir)
{
  if (dir == CCW)
  {
    // Start moving motor towards the endstop.
    while (motor->endstop_status != 1)
    {
      if (motor == Motor_M1)
        Start_M1_CCW();
      else if (motor == Motor_M2)
        Start_M2_CCW();
      else if (motor == Motor_M3)
        Start_M3_CCW();
      else if (motor == Motor_M4)
        Start_M4_5_CCW();
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to compare `Motor_Params *motor` to its instance declaration that way I can use this fn for multiple motors. When I try compiling this, I get,

```
error: invalid operands to binary == (have 'Motor_Params *' and 'Motor_Params')
  if (motor == Motor_M1)
```

How do I compare `Motor_Params *motor` to any of its instance declarations?

Comment: Are `Motor_M1` etc fixed sets of parameters or can they be changed in run-time?

Comment: `else if (motor == Motor_M3) Start_M3_CCW(); else if (motor == Motor_M4) Start_M4_5_CCW();` This looks like it could use just one function pointer inside `Motor_Params` instead.

Comment: Also... I hope this code isn't from a real industrial control system...? Just some school project, right?

Comment: @Lundin yes they can be changed in run-time. And no, it's not in any control system. Just testing some stuff but now I'm curious why you'd ask this.

Comment: @electrophile Because some of the terms you use here like "end stop" are very similar to those used for industrial cranes. And they most often have exactly 4 motors.

Comment: @Lundin Ah I see. I did not know that. This is not for that though. This is a custom project for a much smaller machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comparison in if statements like this

```
if (motor == Motor_M1)
```

does not make a sense. That is motor is a pointer of the type `Motor_Params *` while `Motor_M1` is an object of the type `Motor_Params`.

If you want to compare two objects of the type `Motor_Params` you need to  compare data members of two objects of the structure type according to your meaning of the equality operation for the structure. That is the built-in operator == is not defined for structures.

Pay attention to that it is a bad idea when a function definition depends on global variables. Instead of these declarations

```
Motor_Params Motor_M1;
Motor_Params Motor_M2;
Motor_Params Motor_M3;
Motor_Params Motor_M4;
```

you could declare an array like for example

```
Motor_Params Motors[4];
```

and pass this array to the function as an argument.

Comment: Thank you. While I understand that you can lose track of fns that can modify global variables, what if they are needed to be global. For instance, in the typedef struct mentioned in my post, the endstop status gets updated by another fn.

Answer (score 1):

Currently you are comparing the pointer and the actual structures. You have to choose either one.

To compare pointers, add `&` to the structures to get pointers of them:

```
      if (motor == &Motor_M1)
        Start_M1_CCW();
      else if (motor == &Motor_M2)
        Start_M2_CCW();
      else if (motor == &Motor_M3)
        Start_M3_CCW();
      else if (motor == &Motor_M4)
        Start_M4_5_CCW();
```

To compare values of the structures, add `*` to `motor` to dereference that:

```
      if (*motor == Motor_M1)
        Start_M1_CCW();
      else if (*motor == Motor_M2)
        Start_M2_CCW();
      else if (*motor == Motor_M3)
        Start_M3_CCW();
      else if (*motor == Motor_M4)
        Start_M4_5_CCW();
```